# ASP.NET web api "Remember Me" functionality using cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement a *"Remember Me"* functionality in my **Web Api** project.

I would like to :

- have the **Remember Me** functionality when the user *Sign In*.
- save a **cookies** for to keep the user always logged in, so that the user no need type the *username* and *password* every single time when they visit the websites.
- Sign the user in by reading the **cookies** that saved on the last login.

One more question that I am thinking about is... I am trying to generate the **cookies** by using `JavaScript` when the user checked the *Remember Me* Checkbox. Is it possible to do this?

OR

I should implement the `RememberMe()` in the `AccountController`??

Addition:
Here's my code in `ApplicationOAuthProvider`.

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);

        if (user == null) {...}

        if (userManager.IsLockedOut(user.Id)) {...}

        if (!(await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, context.Password)))
        { ... }

        if (!user.EmailConfirmed) {...}

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
```

In my JavaScript.

```
$('#checkbox').click(function () {

    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        // save username and password
        username = $('#txtLoginEmail').val();
        password = $('#pass').val();
        checkbox = $('#chkRememberMe').val();
    } else {
        username = '';
        password = '';
        checkbox = '';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement **refresh tokens** in you app to be able to offer this functionality.

Basically, you need to create a `RefreshTokenOAuthProvider` that will generate refresh tokens. You can use 2 types of `client_id` to make a difference between clients who need to be remembered or not.

It is explained in [this excellent series of blog posts](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) (though it might start to become a little bit outdated, the information regarding owin setup is gold).

Comment: I think your link in incorrect. [This](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) is the right one