# Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web Api: Using asp.net identity cookies for a remember me function in combination with a jwt token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I am making a Web Api that uses jwt web tokens in combination with asp.net identity for authorization. now I am trying to create a remember me function by making use of the authorization cookies that identity offers.

The problem is, I cant seem to figure out how to implement them. The cookie gets created as I login with the remember me function but I dont know how I can validate that cookie when I reload the page. I cant seem to find anything about it online so I am starting to think it would not be common practice to use jwt tokens in combination with cookies.

It was my plan that when a user logs in with "remember me", a web token and a cookie gets created. If the user had selected "remember me" a the cookie gets validated, a new token gets created and the user gets signed in.

so my questions are

1. Is it seen as bad practice to use cookies in combination with jwt token 
   validation?
2. If so how would you recommend a remember me function with a jwt token
3. If not, how can I acces the cookie, decrypt it and get the data needed to 
   login.

many thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK, the only thing "remember me" does is that instead of a session cookie you get a persistent cookie with a 2 week expiration.  What are you using JWT for, is it for SPA or external access?

Comment: @MarkG I use it for SPA

Comment: Take a look at [ASP.NET web api “Remember Me” functionality using cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399859/asp-net-web-api-remember-me-functionality-using-cookies) and see if that helps.